# Difference between java servlet developing and php

Tags: php, servlets, web

I have to develope an e-commerce and I'm not sure what kind of technologies use. So I ask you the difference between developing by java servlet or by php.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are atleast 500 factors to chose from. Starting from your requirement ending at your competency and resources available.

Comment: You have no idea what the difference is between Java and PHP? Good luck with your e-commerce site... It is like saying that you are going to build a house and then asking how to use a ruler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making web app using java servlets is time consuming but it has lot of advantages over php.

Java servlets app are scalable. Java Community provides several framework to minimize the dependency(loose coupling)

So if you  want to really make web app for commercial transaction where millions of users do transaction go for Java Servlets.